# Bash command output as variable returning /bin/bash

Tags: bash

When I run the following command in my terminal I get the expected value :

```
delayedjobs="$(ps aux | grep delayed_job | grep -v grep | awk '{print $11}' | awk 'END{print}' | cut -d "." -f2)" && echo $delayedjobs
```

However, when I run the following script, the variable returns as "/bin/bash"

```
#!/bin/bash

delayedjobs="$(ps aux | grep delayed_job | grep -v grep | awk '{print $11}' | awk 'END{print}' | cut -d "." -f2)"

echo ${delayedjobs}


root@central:/home/tblake# ./myscript.sh
/bin/bash
```

Can anyone explain this?  Im having a heck of a time figuring this out.

Answer (score 1):

Has you named your skript delayed_job ? Your script detect his own process.

Comment: omg... what a brain fart.  I had named my script delayed_job_mon.sh.  Im embarrased.